# index and NOT operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am reading MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit for 70-433 exam.

And it says that query optimizer cannot use indexes for the WHERE clause when a NOT operator is specified.

I suspect it is connected to search mechanism, but I would like to know the SQL professionals opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to pick all the rows not meeting a condition, you need to examine all rows.

Since you have to visit all rows, an index won't help..

Comment: Nice phrasing... what I *wanted* to say

Answer (score 4):

Correct. It's exclusive, not inclusive. Or inequality, not equality

That is, you have to check all rows: you can't seek to your values.

Edit... and a [link](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/t_sql_where_p2.aspx) that captures it quite well